# TypeScript: is it possible to dynamically refer to an interface and make it inherit from other entities through a decorator?

Tags: typescript, interface

For example, something like that

```js
function doInterfaceInheritance<T>(...entities: Function[]) {
    return (target: T) => {
        // ... a code to implement a mixing in fact

        declare interface targert extends ...entities {}
    }
}

class Class1 {

    private instanceProperty: string;

    static staticClassProperty: string = `class property defined in ${this.name}`;

    constructor() {
        this.instanceProperty = `instance property defined in ${Class1.name}`;
    }

    instanceMethod(): string {
        return this.instanceProperty;
    }

    staticPropertyAccessedThoughAnInstanceMethod(): string {
        return `${Class1.staticClassProperty} accessed through a method`;
    }

}

@doInterfaceInheritance<MixedClass>(Class1)
class MixedClass {

}

// I want not to have to do this
interface MixedClass extends Class1 {

}

const mixedClass = new MixedClass();

console.log(mixedClass.instanceMethod())
```

[here](https://tsplay.dev/dinamically-inheritance) is the code that I'm testing.

Comment: _Why_ do you want to do this?

Comment: @Dai nothing concrete. Just to find out if it's possible.

Comment: decorators can't change the type of the class. This is usually done through a function